# Directive for including a raw HTML file in a ReStructured Text page

Tags: html, iframe, restructuredtext

I have a `.rst` page that I am rendering. I would like to create an `IFrame` in it containing an `example.html` page from the same directory, or find some similar alternative way of hosting the `HTML` on the page. What is the easiest way of achieving this?

---

I've tried a couple of approaches so far. (1):

```
.. include:: ./example.html
```

This renders the HTML as if it were a text file.

(2):

```
.. raw:: html

    <iframe src="./example.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="width:960px; height:600px; border:0; overflow:hidden;">
    </iframe>
```

This results in an embedded 404 page (but will it display properly once I get everything server-hosted?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the include file directive, then in the html file you are including, use:

```
.. raw:: html

   html content
```

Comment: This is an *awfully* clever trick that works. Hopefully future authors sharing my predicament will find their way here!